# Clang gives confusing error message "expected value in expression"

Tags: c, clang, c-preprocessor

I'm getting the following error message from Clang 10:

```
error: expected value in expression
#if FOOBAR
          ^
1 error generated.
```

No further info. What could be the cause for this?

Comment: maybe you wanted `#ifdef` ? `#if` is expecting an expression.

Comment: How is `FOOBAR` defined? (Or is it defined?) Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve] please.

Comment: [I got the error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A6WhQVyuWJfbcERy) by adding `#define FOOBAR` before the line.

Comment: The error isn't in my code so I can't produce a reproducible example as I don't understand it.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thx! Could be that the variable is defined as empty. I will look into it.

Comment: Yes the variable is defined empty.

Comment: The missing variable is #if INCLUDE_SYS_TYPES_H how can I with CMake set the path to the types.h file. The system folder changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the cause for this?

When the macro is defined to nothing

```
#define FOOBAR
```

then

```
#if FOOBAR
```

expands to just:

```
#if
```

And compiler prints an error - `if` needs an expression `#if something-here`.